# Flex: Modules v/s Components for a large scale project

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am planning on a Flex project that involves incorporation of a lot of features.

Each 'feature' can be a component / module.

Which is preferred and what is the difference between a module and a component?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it depends.

If you going to use all, or most, of your components during regular execution of the application - components would be alright.

By the sounds of things though, modules might be the better bet for your project.

Modules allow you to group components into external libraries (RSLs).  These libraries can be embedded into your application (through project settings) or can be loaded dynamically at runtime (as separate files).

Modules would give you some benefits

1. Only loading the libraries needed (as needed) instead of all modules everytime.
2. Load only core modules initially to speed up the initial load time.
3. Changes to a component do not require you to recompile the application/

Find out more about creating modules [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=creating_modules_2.html).